# Is it possible to sniff packets from a client connected router via Wi-Fi while I am connected through Ethernet?

Tags: wireshark

How to sniff packets (using wireshark) from the other client connected to the same router (Linksys) but through Ethernet cable while I’m connected to that router via Wi-Fi.

Is it possible?

Comment: Using some ARP exploits or some similar technique, you may be able to reroute packets through your device.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, because router routes packets within. This would be possible on hub or Wi-Fi but not on router with Ethernet connection.